# SQL Server Express Fargate health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, sql-server-express, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

How do you add a Healthcheck that will pass for a AWS TargetGroup to sit in front of an SQL Server Express container running in ECS/Fargate?

Do I need to have a ghetto side car service hosting "OK" on a port that I can use to verify it's working?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a Network Load Balancer for this, not an ALB. For the target group you would configure a TCP health check, not HTTP/HTTPS. A TCP health check just verifies that a TCP connection can be established. You would configure the TCP health check to connect to the SQL Server port.

Comment: i've got one like that setup and the health checks still always fail.. :(

Comment: The failure could be due to the security groups on the Fargate tasks. It's hard to help you if you don't provide all the details of your configuration.

Comment: i understand, thanks for taking time to respond.

Comment: seems like it was security groups, but I was reading where the network load balancers didn't use those, but I must have misinterpreted what that meant. I did eventually get it working completely in the cloudformation stack script.